# Rendering XML inside text area

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a react code which returns XML from my API now I want to display the same XML inside a text area is the a way to achieve that?

> class XmlCall extends Component {   constructor(props) {
>       super(props);
>       this.state = {
>         callBackData: []
>       };   }

Comment: can you add more code of the XmlCall component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having fetched your xml from the API in a componentDidMount function, you could have a render method which contains a  html tag with the xml.

```
class XmlCall extends Component { 
 constructor(props) { 
  super(props); this.state = { callBackData: [] }; 
 }
 componentDidMount(){
  const fetchedData = //Fetch with an API like fetch or axios. Careful with async functions here.
  this.setState(callBackData: fetchedData); 
 }
 render(){
  return(
   <div>
    <textarea>{this.state.callBackData}</textarea>
   </div>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign it to a variable and render it. React will take care that the rendered content is escaped properly.

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLwr2bs3/1/).

```js
  render() {
    const xmlcontent = '<test></test>'

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Textarea:</h2>
        <textarea>{xmlcontent}</textarea>
      </div>
    )
  }
```